# Denseness of simple functions $S[a,b]$ in piecewise continuous functions $PC[a,b]$ in supremum norm $||f||_\infty=\sup(f(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

$PC[a,b]$ is the family of all bounded piecewise continuos functions on $[a,b]$ which is continuous from right i.e. $\lim_{x\downarrow y}f(x)=f(y)$ and for which $\lim_{x\downarrow y}f(x)$ exists at each y and is equal to $f(y)$ for all $y$ except but finitely many.

**My Attempt**

This problem felt like a simple amplication of uniform continuity but the function
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac{1}{(a+1)-x}\right) \ \ &x\in[a,a+1) \\ x &x\in[a+1,b]\end{cases}$$ is in $PC[a,b]$ while not uniformly continuous. Any other way i could think of has its own flaws due to supremum norm so.

Thank you for your answers.

**Proof:** By help of *Kavi Rama Murthy* i checked the definition and realized we have left continuity as well which means.

If $f$ is bounded piecewise continuous function. Then we could split it into continuos functions $f_k$  on domains $[x_k,x_{k+1})$ with $a\leq x_k < x_{k+1}\leq b$. By left continuity $\lim_{x\uparrow x_{k+1}}f_k(x) $ exists (but not necessarily equal to $f(x_{k+1})$).

Remaining follows from using uniform boundedness of continuous functions on compact intervals and choosing the smallest $\delta_k$ which makes all $|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-y|<\delta=\min\{\delta_1,...,\delta_n\}$ with $x,y\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]$

Comment: I think this function is not in $PC[a,b]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you tell me why it is not in $PC[a,b]$. Maybe i'm missing something obvious but it seems like it is bounded,right continuous and piecewise continuous. (Of course i'm assuming $a, b$ is not $\infty$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f \notin PC[a,b]$:

Let $0 <\epsilon<\frac  1 4$, $x_n=a+1-\frac  1{\frac {\pi} 2+2n\pi}$ and $y_n=a+1-\frac  1{ {n\pi}}$. Suppose there is a piece-wise continuous function $g$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|
 <\epsilon$ for all $x$. Then $$|1-0|=|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|$$ $$\leq |f(x_n)-g(x_n)|+|g(x_n)-g(y_n)|+|g(y_n)-f(y_n)|$$ $$<2\epsilon +|g(x_n)-g(y_n)|.$$ Since $g$ has a left-hand limit at $a+1$ it follows that $|g(x_n)-g(y_n)| \to 0$ as  $n\to \infty$. Hence, for $n$ large enough we get $|1-0| <3\epsilon <\frac  3  4$, a contradiction.

Comment: $g$ does not need to have left-hand limit. And i don't see why $g+|g(x_n)+g(y_n)|$ should have left-hand limit.

Comment: What is your definition of  a piece-wise continuous function?  Doesn't such a function have a left-hand limit at every point? (BTW I have corrected  a  typo in my answer). @OğuzhanKılıç

Comment: I changed the definition and now i realise we must have left-hand limit at every point. Then your answer is correct. My function is not in $PC[a,b]$. Sorry for lack of information. But can i ask you why do we have the condition left-hand limit exists in the definition of piecewise contunuity? Also I believe i can use uniform continuity to prove main question with left-handed limits exists condition.

Comment: Also we should have $y_n=a+1-\frac  1{ {n\pi}}$ minor detail but... Thank you for your answer by the way it was very helpful.

Comment: A function $g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is called piece-wise continuous if there is a partition $\{x_i\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that $g$ is continuous on each if the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. $g$  is continuous at all point except the points $x_i$. At these points it has left-hand and right-hand limits but the two limits may be different. @OğuzhanKılıç